# Reaction of styrene oxide with hydrogen iodide

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

The question is to find the product of the reaction of [Styrene Oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styrene_oxide) with Hydrogen Iodide.

According to me, this should be the mechanism-
[image]

As the benzylic carbocation will be more stable, therefore the product made from A should be major and the other one should be minor. But, in my book the answer to this question is the opposite of mine. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did your book mention cyclodextrin? In its presence iodide opening at the primary site.

Comment: No, only the structure of the two reactants was given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is the correct one. Acid-catalysed hydrolysis of epoxides proceeds exactly as shown. In the specific case of styrene oxide, nucleophiles attach themselves to the benzylic carbon<sup>1,2</sup>, which means that **A** should be the major product. I'm attaching an image from (1) which gives the products of reaction of methanol with styrene oxide:
[image: styrene oxide with methanol]

If you want to, you can try to drop a note to the authors of your book about this error.

**References:**

1. Mohseni, Sharareh, et al. “Theoretical and Experimental Studies on the Regioselectivity of Epoxide Ring Opening by Nucleophiles in Nitromethane without Any Catalyst: Nucleophilic-Chain Attack Mechanism.” Progress in Reaction Kinetics and Mechanism, vol. 39, no. 1, **2014**, *pp. 89–102*. doi:[10.3184/97809059274714X13874723178403](https://doi.org/10.3184/97809059274714X13874723178403).
2. Morrison, Robert Thornton, and Robert Neilson Boyd. Organic Chemistry. 5. ed, Allyn and Bacon, **1987**, *pp. 780-785*.